# How do I check that this is a Frobenius algebra?

Tags: ac.commutative-algebra, ra.rings-and-algebras, frobenius-algebras

Let $f_1,f_2,\ldots,f_n\in \mathbb C[z_1,\ldots, z_n]$ be such that the quotient ring
$$A:=\mathbb C[z_1,\ldots, z_n]/(f_1,f_2,\ldots,f_n)$$
is finite dimensional (in other words, it's a zero-dimensional complete intersection).
I've heard that such a ring is always a Frobenius algbera when equipped with the counit
$$
\varepsilon(g):= \int_{|f_1|=\ldots=|f_n|=1} \frac{g(z_1,\ldots,z_n)}{\prod_i f_i(z_1,\ldots,z_n)}dz_1\ldots dz_n,
$$
and I'd like to check that claim. By definition, $A$ is a Frobenius algebra if the bilinear form $\langle g,h\rangle:=\varepsilon(gh)$ is non-degenerate. 
So I would like to know whether:

> If $g\in \mathbb C[z_1,\ldots, z_n]$ is such that
>   $$\int_{|f_1|=\ldots=|f_n|=1} \frac{g(z_1,\ldots,z_n)h(z_1,\ldots,z_n)}{\prod_i f_i(z_1,\ldots,z_n)}dz_1\ldots dz_n=0$$
>   for every $h\in \mathbb C[z_1,\ldots, z_n]$, does is then follow that $g$ is in the ideal generated by $f_1,f_2,\ldots,f_n$?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Yes, this is discussed in page 659 of "Principles of Algebraic Geometry" by Griffiths and Harris. They call it *the local duality theorem*.

Comment: Ok. I'll check it out. Is it easy to say what kind of ingredients come into the proof?

Comment: @AndréHenriques The main steps are roughly: 1) Reduce the global duality theorem (the statement in your question) to the local case around a single zero. 2) Prove it for the case $f_i=z_i^{k_i}$. 3) Deduce the general form by using the transformation formula (which says that if you take the residue with respect to $Af$ then the residue changes by factor of $\det (A)$.)